# Null ID on persisted objects - GORM marks object loaded from database as unsaved

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Recently I have started refactoring my Grails application, everything looked good until I got '**object references an unsaved transient instance**' errors. While debugging I have found that id for one of my domain object is always null for every instance. Even for instances loaded from database.
I have found that composite id (which I use in that class) is known to cause problems, but it worked fine few days ago, since then, I have done a lot changes to this class but none of them should cause this kind of problems... at least I couldn't find change that could cause it.

```
class QuestionPriority implements Serializable{

static int maxPriority = 6
static int minPriority = 1
int priority = maxPriority
Date lastTestDate
Date nextTestDate = new Date()

static belongsTo = [question:Question, subscription:Subscription]

static constraints = {
    nextTestDate(nullable: true)
    lastTestDate(nullable: true)
}

static mapping = {
    id composite: ['subscription', 'question']
    version false
}

static QuestionPriority create(Subscription sub, Question question, boolean flush = false) {
    assert sub != null
    assert question != null
    assert sub.id != null
    assert question.id != null

    QuestionPriority qp = new QuestionPriority(subscription: sub, question: question)
    sub.addToPriorities(qp)
    question.addToPriorities(qp)
    assert (qp.save(flush: flush, insert: true, failOnError: true))
    return qp
}

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof QuestionPriority)) {
        return false
    }

    other.subscription?.id == subscription?.id &&
            other.getQuestionToAsk?.id == question?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (subscription) builder.append(subscription.id)
    if (question) builder.append(question.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}

void markAsCorrect() {
    priorityDown()
    calculateNextTestDate()
}

void markAsWrong() {
    priorityUp()
    calculateNextTestDate()
}

String getQuestionToAsk() {
    return question.question
}

String getExpectedAnswer() {
    return question.answer
}

Date calculateNextTestDate() {
    DailyTestMode mode = subscription.testMode
    if (!lastTestDate) {
        nextTestDate = new Date(0, 0, 0)
    } else {
        nextTestDate = mode.calculateNextAskDate(this)
    }
    return nextTestDate
}

static void delete(User user, Question q) {
    QuestionPriority qp = get(user.id, q)
    if (qp) {
        qp.delete()
    }
}

static QuestionPriority get(Subscription sub, Question question) {
    assert sub != null
    assert question != null
    assert sub.id != null
    assert question.id != null

    QuestionPriority qp = find 'from QuestionPriority where subscription.id=:subId and question.id=:questionId',
            [subId: sub.id, questionId: question.id]
    if (!qp) {
        qp = create(sub, question)
    }
    return qp
}

private void priorityUp() {
    priority = Math.min(priority + 1, maxPriority)
    lastTestDate = new Date()
    calculateNextTestDate()
}

private void priorityDown() {
    priority = Math.max(priority - 1, minPriority)
    lastTestDate = new Date()
    calculateNextTestDate()
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help

-----EDIT-------

**Question domain oject:**
    class Question {

```
String question
String answer
boolean deleted

static transients = [ 'deleted']
static belongsTo = [studyList: StudyList]
static hasMany = [priorities: QuestionPriority]

static constraints = {
    question(blank:false)
    answer(blank:false)
}

static mapping = {
    priorities(cascade: 'all-delete-orphan')
}

void setAnswer(String a){
    answer = a.trim()
}

String toString(){
    return "${question} = ${answer}"

}
}
```

**Subscription domain object**

```
class Subscription implements Serializable {

boolean active = true
Integer rating = null
Date subscriptionStartDate = new Date()
String dailyTestModeLiteral

static belongsTo = [user:User, studyList:StudyList]
static hasMany = [priorities:QuestionPriority]

static constraints = {
    priorities(nullable: true)
    rating(nullable: true)
    subscriptionStartDate(nullable: true)
}

static mapping = {
    priorities(cascade: 'all-delete-orphan')
}

void setDailyTestMode(DailyTestMode mode){
    dailyTestModeLiteral = mode.getModeLiteral()
    for(QuestionPriority priority:priorities){
        priority.calculateNextTestDate()
    }
}

DailyTestMode getTestMode(){
    return DailyTestMode.getMode(dailyTestModeLiteral)
}

public static Subscription create(User user, StudyList list, String testModeLiteral = NormalDailyTestStrategy.literal, boolean flush = false){
    Subscription subscription = get(user.id, list.id)
    if(!subscription){
        withTransaction {
            subscription = new Subscription(user: user, studyList: list, dailyTestModeLiteral: testModeLiteral)
            user.addToSubscriptions(subscription)
            list.addToSubscriptions(subscription)
            subscription.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
        }
        subscription.studyList.questions.each {
            QuestionPriority.create(subscription, it)
        }
    }
    return subscription
}


int getScore(){
    float prioritySum = 0
    float priorityMax = 0
    float priorityMin = 0
    priorities.each {
        prioritySum += it.priority
        priorityMin += 1
        priorityMax += QuestionPriority.maxPriority
    }
    return Math.round(100 * (prioritySum-priorityMax)/(priorityMin - priorityMax))
}

public static void delete(User user, StudyList list){
    Subscription subscription = get(user.id, list.id)
    if(subscription){
        subscription.delete()
    }
}

static Subscription get(long userId, long studyListId) {
    find 'from Subscription where user.id=:userId and studyList.id=:studyListId',
            [userId: userId, studyListId: studyListId]

}

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Subscription)) {
        return false
    }

    other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.studyList?.id == studyList?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (user) builder.append(user.id)
    if (studyList) builder.append(studyList.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}

boolean checkIfMatches(QuestionPriority questionPriority, String questionAsked, String answerGiven) {
    return(questionPriority.question.question==questionAsked &&
        questionPriority.question.answer == answerGiven)
}

QuestionPriority checkIfMatchesAny(String questionAsked, String answerGiven) {
    Question q = Question.withCriteria {
        and {
            eq('question', questionAsked)
            eq('answer', answerGiven)
            eq('studyList', studyList)
        }
    }
    if(q){
        List<QuestionPriority> qp = QuestionPriority.withCriteria {
            and {
                eq('question', q)
                eq('subscription', this)
            }
        }
        if(qp.size()>0){
            return qp[0]
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }
}
}
```

A few hours of debuging later I still know only that executing `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` on QuestionPriority object returns unsaved object (no validation errors, no exceptions... no helpful information).

Any idea where to look or how to search for cause of this problem would be helpful, because I'm 100% stuck on this...

Comment: Am I missing something? I'm not seeing `subscription` or `question` fields for this class.

Comment: I didn't add other classes, since I've hoped that more experienced programmer will find some obvious error in QuestionPriority class. I didn't want my question to be too long

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, changing framework to newest version and fixing new problems resulting from version change, I fixed this problem. It looks like changing composite ID into normal ID + composite unique key solved the problem. I couldn't find other solution, even thou my code worked fine with composite id for first couple of months... (any part of code related to composite id was changed when it stopped working) and I'm almost sure that I tried removing composite ID earlier and it didn't help then...